# What is the value of this capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, component-values

I have a bunch of these, and I can't remember what I thought they were when I bought them. I've googled a ton of possible (yet conflicting) potential value options. Looking for some expert advice.

The only markings on them are: "0.1 K 100"

[image: top markings][image: keyboard key size reference]

Comment: 100 pF. Probably 100 V rating.

Comment: Should be 0.1uF / 100V  with a capacitance tolerance of 10% (K=10%, J=5%, F=1%)

Comment: By the size of it, I'd vote 0.1uF

Comment: Why don't you just measure them?  Even cheap DMMs have capacitance ranges.

Answer (score 3):

### Definitely 100nF (0.1µF) and 100V

Considering the lack of other markings on the part, this is definitely a 0.1µF (100nF), 100V capacitor; it is *likely* a monolithic ceramic type, but could be a film part as well.  It will work just fine for non-critical applications (such as decoupling), but I wouldn't use a cap like this in a signal path unless I knew more about it.

The other possibilities are 100pF and 0.1pF -- the former I can safely rule out as that'd be notated as "100 J 100" or something of that ilk instead, and 0.1pF is an insanely low value for a through-hole capacitor; a 0.1pF capacitor would get swamped by the parasitic capacitance of its own leads!